# An assertion on the test case file - Webdriverio

Tags: ui-automation, webdriver-io

I need some help, I'm starting with this automation stuff, I like it but I'm still learning, recently I create a test case that basically is, going to a certain page and click on a button to upgrade the account on an specific sale, so I did that but when I got my PR reviewed and devops ask me if I can add an assertion.

So, this code is on the spec file not on the page objects file, so the devops mean I have to create the code on the page object file and then call it on the spec file???? any tip would be great and thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it either way. You can write the assertion in the spec file, or write the assertion in the page objects file and call it from the specs file. If the latter is your framework's code convention, you may want to do it that way for consistency, but either way should work.

Comment: Thanks!!! I did it in the spec file and the PR was approved by the dev!! thanks for the answer!!!